# How to show footer menu as show and hide

Tags: jquery

My website has menus in footer and it loooks great for desktop but i want to show these menus as show and hide jquery items for mobile means plus to open and minus to close ..i dont have much knoweldge about jquery , so any one please help me with this please .... Footer menus html are below

`html`

```
<ul class="open">
    <li><a href="#">OUR PHILOSOPHY</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ANTI-MALWARE</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ANTI-VIRUS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ANTISPAM</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">FIREWALL</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">BACKUP & RECOVERY</a></li>

</ul>
```

`js`

```
<script>
    function mobile() {
        if ($(window).width() < 500) {

            console.log('is mobile');

            $("#mobile-tabs .open").hide();
            $("#mobile-tabs h1").click(function() {
                $(this).next("#mobile-tabs .open").slideToggle(500);
                $(this).toggleClass("expanded");
            });
        }
    }

    $(window).resize(mobile);
    mobile();
</script>
```

Comment: show us what you tried

Comment: @madalin ivascu Please check again i put all my  code

Comment: you want a acordeon like this :http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion ??

Answer (score 0):

```
<footer>
<div id="block">
<a href="#" class="expandBtn" id="expand">Mobile Footer Expand 1 </a>
<ul class="open" id="open">
    <li><a href="#">OUR PHILOSOPHY</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ANTI-MALWARE</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ANTI-VIRUS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ANTISPAM</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">FIREWALL</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">BACKUP & RECOVERY</a></li>

</ul>  
</div>
    <div id="block">
<a href="#" class="expandBtn" id="expand">Mobile Footer Expand 2 </a>
<ul class="open" id="open">
    <li><a href="#">OUR PHILOSOPHY 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ANTI-MALWARE 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ANTI-VIRUS 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ANTISPAM 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">FIREWALL 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">BACKUP & RECOVERY 2</a></li>

</ul>  
</div>
    <div id="block">
<a href="#" class="expandBtn" id="expand">Mobile Footer Expand 3 </a>
<ul class="open" id="open">
    <li><a href="#">OUR PHILOSOPHY 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ANTI-MALWARE 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ANTI-VIRUS 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ANTISPAM 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">FIREWALL 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">BACKUP & RECOVERY 3</a></li>

</ul>  
</div>
</footer>



    <script>
        function mobile() {
                  if($(window).width() < 500) {

                    console.log('is mobile');           

                    $("footer #open").hide();
                    $('footer #expand').show();
                    $("footer #block #expand").unbind('click').click(function () { 
                    $("footer #open").hide();
                      $(this).parent().find('#open').toggle();
                    });
                  }else{
                      $("footer #open").show();
                      $('footer #expand').hide();
                  }
                }

                $(window).resize(mobile);
                mobile();
        </script>
```

> Demo https://jsfiddle.net/tqckrzc5/
>
> Demo 2 (block links) https://jsfiddle.net/tqckrzc5/1/

Comment: Ok it works but i have 3 columns lso will you please send me code for all 3 columns